# Adding in the weight parameter for PyTorch's cross-entropy loss causes datatype RuntimeError

Tags: pytorch

I'm currently using PyTorch to train a neural network. The dataset that I'm using is a binary classification dataset with a large number of 0's.

I decided to try and use the `weight` parameter of PyTorch's cross-entropy loss. I calculated the weights via `sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight` and got weight values of `[0.58479532, 3.44827586]`.

When I added this `class_weights` tensor into the `weight` parameter of my loss (i.e., `criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)`, I'm suddenly getting a `RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double`. The outputs and labels that I'm feeding into my loss are of types `float32` and `int64`, respectively. The loss was working fine but when I add the weight parameter I'm getting this error. Attempting to cast my data via `outputs.float()` doesn't seem to work either.

Does anybody know why this error may be occurring and how I might fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Try ensuring that your `class_weights` tensor has `float32` datatype.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a tensor from your weights as follows.
Also, remember to match the devices between the weights and the rest of your tensors.

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
weights =  torch.tensor([0.58479532, 3.44827586],dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
```